# Spring Social Twitter - User Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, twitter, twitter-oauth, spring-social

I'm new to Spring Social and I'm writing a Spring MVC application which users should use for, let's say, tweet, follow/unfollow users. So far I can do everything I want with my own credentials (stored in a property file) using the **TwitterTemplate**.

I need the application to do the same on behalf of other users (authenticating them when registering in my application).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at [this part of Spring Social reference document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/serviceprovider.html#service-providers-persisting-connections) as an entry point. I have experienced it with facebook and linked in and it works pretty well to store connections credentials in a database.

You also want to make sure I guess that you do not use the `ProviderSignInController` highlighted in some of the code samples which is designed for using the social provider as an authentication infrastructure for a web application but a ConnectController which has proved to be efficient in offline access cases. See section 4 of the spring social reference documentation.